# Function keys not working after installing generic Kernel 4.18.0 on Ubuntu 18.04.3

Tags: 18.04, kernel

I have installed a new **kernel 4.18.20** from kernel.ubuntu.com using `dpkg` and removed the **kernel 4.18.0**, which previously came with Ubuntu 18.04.2. Now while using the new kernel, I cannot lock my screen using `super+L`. However I was able to do that before. Now i am trying to install the old kernel that previously came with Ubuntu using Synaptic Package Manager. So far I have installed:

```
linux-image-4.18.0-25-generic
linux-headers-4.18.0-25
linux-headers-4.18.0-25-generic
```

And then i have updated the grub. Now when I login to the **kernel 4.18.0**, I cannot use wifi, bluetooth neither can i lower the screen brightness or sound using `fn` + any function key. Please offer your kind help.

Comment: The kernel 4.18 series came with Ubuntu 18.10, which is now EOL, so I'd suggest using either the standard 4.15 kernel of 18.04, or the HWE kernel of 18.04 (which is currently 5.0), ie. switch back to a supported (and automatically upgraded kernel)

Comment: @guiverc I think previously 4.15 came by default then it was upgraded using apt-get  to 4.18 and then to 5.0. Bu i had another problem is the nvidia graphic card which only works in kernel 4.18

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (either from release-upgrade from 16.04, or new install with the 18.04 or 18.04.1 ISO) had 4.15 kernel. New installs using 18.04.2 or later (eg. recent 18.04.3) or if HWE was enabled, caused switch to 18.10 kernel (now EOL), then 19.04 kernel (current 5.0 kernel), and will get 19.10 & 20.04 kernel in the future. 4.18 is EOL & not getting updates, so I'd suggest returning to the non-HWE 4.15 kernel for security reasons (*also note: if you are using a test 4.18 series kernel, not all features may be enabled or compiled into kernel*)

Comment: @guiverc i am using the kernel from this link https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.18.20/